# Typescript make variable act as pointer to another variable

Tags: angular, typescript

Lets say I have some component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-view',
    templateUrl: './view.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./view.component.scss']
})

export class ViewComponent implements OnInit {
    // used to alias the actual user data, set with OnInit
    private plan: string;
    private status: string;
    private started: string;
    private cycle: string;

    constructor (private auth: Auth, private modal: Modal, private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // without these shorthand names the components code would be messy and unreadable
        this.plan = this.auth.userProfile.user_metadata.plan;
        this.status = this.auth.userProfile.user_metadata.token.status;
        this.started = this.auth.userProfile.user_metadata.token.epoch;
        this.cycle = this.auth.userProfile.user_metadata.cycle;

        // do stuff using alias variables so I don't have to use extremely long names
        if(this.plan === .... && this.cycle === ...) {

        }
    }
}
```

This scenario allows me to use much shorter and simpler variable names instead of the long names I would normally use to access user data, **But** this breaks when the user data is updated while on this page.

Since the alias variables are only set during `onInit`, when a change to the user data occurs these variables don't reflect that change and the user would need to refresh the whole page to see the change.

Is there any way to easily do something like this, but have the variables like `plan, status, started, cycle` observe the original value and update accordingly? Otherwise I'd need to use the long names and sacrifice the readability of my code.

Comment: You could make it a bit shorter by referencing `user_metadata` and change the properties of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use getter functions or ES6 properties for this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-view',
    templateUrl: './view.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./view.component.scss']
})
export class ViewComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor (private auth: Auth, private modal: Modal, private router: Router) {}

    private get plan(): string { // property
        return this.auth.userProfile.user_metadata.plan;
    }

    private getStatus(): string { // getter
        return this.auth.userProfile.user_metadata.status;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        if(this.plan === .... && this.getStatus() === ...) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Primitive values like `string`, `number`, `boolean` are always passed by value.
Objects are passed by reference. It seems what you want is "pass by reference" for primitive type.

What you can do is to wrap the values with an object and pass that object instead.

It's usually a better way to use observables to notify interested other class instances about value changes.

For examples see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: The issue is that I don't really have a parent-child relationship for my code structure. I have a `ProfileModule` with it's main component being `ProfileComponent` and a collection of children that are either lazy loaded or loaded directly. Looking at the examples I don't think I can apply any of them to my code structure

Comment: Thus is not limited to parent child. This caption is quite unfortunate becaus this pattern is especially used if there is **no** parent-child relation becausr in this case the other simpler strategies can be used.